# What's the deal with trailing white space in TSQL queries?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For example, if I have this data:

```
CREATE TABLE FooBar ( Name varchar(16) )

INSERT FooBar SELECT 'test@test.com'
```

The following queries don't return what I would expect:

```
SELECT * FROM FooBar WHERE Name = 'test@test.com       '  -- Returns the row

SELECT * FROM FooBar WHERE Name LIKE 'test@test.com '  -- Nothing Returned

SELECT * FROM FooBar WHERE Name = ' test@test.com' -- Nothing Returned
```

Why does `=` (which I assume means exactly equals) with extra space at the end return data, while a `LIKE` does not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seing the standard it depends on **padding** (The ANSI standard requires padding for the character strings used in comparisons so that their lengths match before comparing them)

> SQL Server follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification (Section 8.2, ,
>   General rules #3) on how to compare strings with spaces. The ANSI
>   standard requires padding for the character strings used in
>   comparisons so that their lengths match before comparing them. The
>   padding directly affects the semantics of WHERE and HAVING clause
>   predicates and other Transact-SQL string comparisons. For example,
>   Transact-SQL considers the strings 'abc' and 'abc ' to be equivalent
>   for most comparison operations.
>
> The only exception to this rule is the LIKE predicate. When the right
>   side of a LIKE predicate expression features a value with a trailing
>   space, SQL Server does not pad the two values to the same length
>   before the comparison occurs. Because the purpose of the LIKE
>   predicate, by definition, is to facilitate pattern searches rather
>   than simple string equality tests, this does not violate the section
>   of the ANSI SQL-92 specification mentioned earlier.

See also [how SQL Server compares strings with trailing spaces](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626)

Comment: This isn't part of your question, but something that has bitten me when I was investigating these sorts of issues is that the LEN function does not count trailing spaces (but the DATALENGTH function does).